# How do I pass values between two wordpress websites?

Tags: php, wordpress

When a user visits a wordpress website, he/she should be redirected to another wordpress website with post title as form data passed on.

I did this using a php, I need to know how I can do the same using wordpress.
This is the code I have used.

```
<?php
session_start();
$title=get_the_title();
$pass_value='https://example.com/reader.php?title='.$title;
?>
<form method='post' action='<?php echo $pass_value?>'>
<div align="center"><input type='submit' name='postread' value='read' /></div>
</form>
```

I have embedded the above code in a php code widget.
The passvalue am catching using a php file that gets the title and processes the title. How do I make a wordpress page do the same.?

Answer (score 0):

How about a curl request and a redirect header?

```
<?php
session_start();
$title=get_the_title();
$pass_value='https://example.com/reader.php?title='.$title;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "title=$title");   
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

header("location: $pass_value")
```

Comment: So I don't need to input any code in the destination website?.

Comment: You need somehow to process the post request

Comment: That's ok, I can process that information in the destination website. But the above code will send the params to the wordpress post??

Comment: The above code will make the request from the server and pass a redirect header to the client.